# Adding a namespace to a Zend_Feed_Writer_Feed

Tags: php, zend-framework, namespaces, atom-feed

I'm working on implementing a feed generator for use with Google Product Search for our sites.  As Zend incorporates a feed writer class, I decided to go with Atom for the feed format.

I've done some work building up a bare-bones Atom feed into which the real product data will be injected, but I've hit a fairly serious snag.

Google want a feed file to be a customised version of either RSS or Atom, with an additional namespace attached for the tags Google Product Search uses.  For example, `<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">`.  I've been trying to figure out how to attach the additional namespace and use it in generating the feed, but Zend's documentation on the matter is vague at best, mentioning something about extensions without going into any great detail.

I did also find mention in the documentation of registering namespaces to zend_feed, so I tried `Zend_Feed::registerNamespace ('g', 'http://base.google.com/ns/1.0')` to attach the needed namespace, but this didn't appear to do anything.

So how do I add additional namespaces to a zend feed?  Does it require subclassing the `zend_feed_writer_feed`?  is there some kind of plugin system that allows this?  Or do I just need to register the namespace somehow?

Comment: It would seem that Zend_Feed has nothing to do with Zend_Feed_Writer, which would explain why registerNamespace didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend from Zend_Feed_Atom and add:

```
class Gordons_Feed_Atom extends Zend_Feed_Atom {
     protected function _mapFeedHeaders($array) {
         $feed = parent::_mapFeedHeaders($array);
         $feed->setAttribute('xmlns:g', '"http://base.google.com/ns/1.0');
         return $feed;
     }
}
```

**Update:**

You will have to override the `_mapFeedEntries` function and then add the entries as the others are added:

```
    $cond = $this->_element->createElement('g:condition');
    $cond->appendChild($this->_element->createCDATASection($dataentry->gcondition));
    $entry->appendChild($cond);
```

You could always do this:

```
protected function _mapFeedEntries(DOMElement $root, $array)
{
    parent::_mapFeedEntries($root, $array);
    foreach($array as $dataentry) {
        //Add you're custom ones
        $cond = $this->_element->createElement('g:condition');
        $cond->appendChild($this->_element->createCDATASection($dataentry->gcondition));
        $entry->appendChild($cond);
    } 
}
```

That function would ensure you get the standard ones and then you're custom ones.

Comment: Okay, that looks like a great start for sure, but how do I then set the Google-specific tags, or add a Google-specific namespace to a standard atom tag?

Comment: That should output your namespace in the standard tag, as this:
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">. I don't really understand, what you need, can you update?

Comment: The Google Merchant feed expects some additional tags from their g: namespace to be mixed in with the standard atom tags.  For example, <g:price>, <g:condition> and <g:availability>.  Once I've got the namespace attached to the feed I also need to be able to add those tags to the feed.  How do I go about doing that?

Comment: @Ashley how have I to create an instance of it? Have I to create a $this->feed = new My_Feed_Writer_Feed ();

Comment: @Mikunos Yes, just as a normal class. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.html

Comment: @Ashley Thanks but I have solved using the Zend_Feed_Writer extension.

Answer (score 0):

**Google Merchant Feed XML Atom 1.0**

I have solved my Zend Framework Google Product issue. What I thought was override the main classes but I have discovered a better solution that I have used in my project.

First of all you need a Zend project :P then you need to create a new Feed Extension creating some folders in your /library/MyProject folder like these:

```
library/Myproject/Feed/
└── Writer
    └── Extension
        └── Google
            ├── Entry.php
            ├── Feed.php
            └── Renderer
                ├── Entry.php
                └── Feed.php
```

then you have to create your own extension. I have created my own extension Google in my own project at http://code.google.com/p/shineisp/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Flibrary%2FShineisp%2FFeed%2FWriter%2FExtension%2FGoogle%253Fstate%253Dclosed

you are free to use my code as you like!

```
.
.
.
.
<entry>
    <title><![CDATA[Hosting Base]]></title>
    <summary><![CDATA[this is the summary.]]></summary>
    <updated>2012-04-23T13:09:55+02:00</updated>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.mysite.com/hosting.html"/>
    <g:id>hosting-base</g:id>
    <g:availability/>
    <g:google_product_category/>
    <g:image_link>http://www.mysite.com/media/products/854_web-hosting-base.gif</g:image_link>
    <g:price>10.89</g:price>
    <g:condition>new</g:condition>
</entry>
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: The provided link is outdated. Would be good to paste the code into the answer directly.