# Zend Feed Writer And Media RSS (Yahoo)

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-feed

Attempting to create a feed with Zend_Feed_Writer but need to include images. 
I checked and such support is offered by Media RSS (Yahoo) and their namespace: http://search.yahoo.com/mrss.

Unfortunately this is not supported by ZendFramework and I am wondering what is the best approach to create such a feed through ZF.

I believe it can be addressed via Extensions but the documentation is poor. Anyone had this need as well?

Comment: Your link results in a 404, update it with the correct one please.

Comment: 404-> It is a namespace URI. See ->http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901316/adding-a-namespace-to-a-zend-feed-writer-feed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create your own Feed_Writer class that extends Zend_Feed_Writer and add methods to support the elements from the [Media RSS specifications](http://www.rssboard.org/media-rss).

From your tags on your question I'm guessing you're using ZF2, right? Couldn't find an example
relating to that version, but here's a good example for creating [Custom Feed and Entry Classes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.feed.custom-feed.html) on ZF1. It shouldn't be too hard to understand the concept and translate it to ZF2.

Hope this helps, good luck.